# How much vinegar and baking soda do i put down my vent to get rid of backed up sewage

Tags: plumbing

How much vinegar and baking soda should I use to unclog a sewer line? When I flush my toilet, it gurgles in the bathroom sink. Does this mean I have a backed up toilet or a backed up sewer line?

Comment: If the toilet flushes ok but makes the sink gurgle then you likely have a plugged vent pipe.

Comment: Putting vinegar and baking soda down the drain is just a waste of vinegar and baking soda.  It won't solve any problem related to this.  Does the toilet flush OK and the problem is just the noise?

Comment: To explain, the sink is gurgling because as the water moves down from the toilet, it create a partial vacuum above the slug of water.  The vent pipe allows air to fill the void.  The gurgle you are hearing is likely air being pulled though the U-shaped trap which is filled with water.  That means the vent is either missing or clogged.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a plugged vent pipe - check your pipe on the roof make sure it is free and clear (no little animals went down it and no birds started to build. Depending on the drain connections and where this toilet is a connecting pipe for a drain vent could also be the culprit.